# Jenkins Job fails when pytest test fails

Tags: jenkins, pytest

Just wanted to explore pytest and integrating it into Jenkins. My sample pytest test cases are

```
def a(x):
    return x+1

def test_answer():
    assert a(2) == 3

def test_answer2():
    assert a(0) == 2
```

I then generated a standalone pytest script which I run in Jenkins, generating an xml to be parsed for results.

As test_answer2 fails, the Jenkins job also fails. I'm assuming this is because the exit code returned is non-zero. How would I go around this, i.e the Jenkins job doesn't even if 1 or more tests do indeed fail. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you want a failed build to act as if it has succeeded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling this test execution in a batch file or shell script or directly using the command execution in Jenkins. You can follow the below way:

```
Windows:

<your test execution calls>

exit 0

Linux:

set +e

<your test execution calls>

set -e
```

This will ignore the error if at all it is called with in the batch scripts and the Jenkins will show status as successful.

Comment: This also worked for me using Bamboo with Linux Build Agent.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to already posted answers:

You also can mark your test as `xfail`, what means `you know it will fail`, just like skipping:

```
@pytest.mark.skip(reason="no way of currently testing this")
def test_the_unknown():
    ...
```

[more about skipping you can find in pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html)

and on Jenkins side you also can manipulate of state of your build via simply try/catch statement:

```
    try {
        bat "python -m pytest ..."
    } catch (pytestError) {
        // rewrite state of you build as you want, Success or Failed
        // currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS" // your case
        println pytestError
    }
```

But be aware, it will mark whole build each time as success for that step of pytest run. Best practice just to skip tests via `@pytest.mark.skip` as described above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this test execution in a batch file or shell script or directly using the command execution in Jenkins. You can follow the below way:
Below code is NOT Working

Linux:

```
set +e
```

```
set -e
```

Answer (score -1):

We use Jenkins running on a Windows system so our tests are listed in the Jenkins "Execute Windows Batch command" section.

I was able to solve this by separating the tests that might have failures with a single `&` (rather than `&&`). For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -c python -m venv env && pip3 install -r requirements.txt && py.test --tap-files test_that_may_fail.py & py.test --tap-files next_test.py & py.test
```

Since we use pytest, any failures are flagged in python with an assert. If you use the `&&`, this will cause Jenkins job to abort and not run the other tests.